# Finding a parent with jQuery

Tags: jquery, selector, parent

I have this code below:

```
<div class="as-mobile-item as-mobile-question">
    <label>Test</label>
    <div>
        <textarea name="as_items" class="form-control input-lg as-task-input as-section-ending" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Given `as-section-ending`, what selector can I use to get the highest level `div`? The one with classes `as-mobile-item as-mobile-question`?

I can't just use a selector for those classes because they exist elsewhere. I specifically need to get the `div` where those classes have that `as-section-ending` child.

Thanks

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: `.closest('.as-mobile-item');` comes to mind.

Comment: `.parent().parent()` but I assume there must be a better way.

Comment: $(".as-section-ending").parent().closest('div')

Comment: so many answers :) , the JavaScript programming becoming very quickly developed these days

Comment: Why do you need jquery for this? Why not just use css? .as-mobile-item as-mobile-question .as-section-ending {Do Stuff; } Even if you only wanted this to be done on one page I believe adding an id to the page then doing #myID .as-mobile-item as-mobile-question .as-section-ending {Do Stuff; } Would be better than adding javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Like this

```js
$(function() {
  var $parentDivs = $(".as-section-ending").closest("div.as-mobile-item.as-mobile-question");
  alert($parentDivs.find("label").text()); // for example
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="as-mobile-item as-mobile-question">
  <label>elsewhere</label>
</div>
<div class="as-mobile-item as-mobile-question">
  <label>Test</label>
  <div>
    <textarea name="as_items" class="form-control input-lg as-task-input as-section-ending" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`var $div = $(".as-section-ending").closest(".as-mobile-item.as-mobile-question")`

jQuery [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) API

Answer (score 0):

use this way

```
$(".as-section-ending").parents().eq(1)
```

After calling **parents()**, it gives Objects containing all parents till root html.
Pass the index number which is parent level and you will get desired parent.
Index number start from 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $elem = $('.as-section-ending');
$elem.parents('div.as-mobile-item.as-mobile-question');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var div= $('.as-section-ending').parents('.as-mobile-item');
```